# Search and find the last pattern character and print the next characters

Tags: linux, text-processing, logs

I have file *C1.log* which has the following:

```
/u01/app/oracle/dirdat/ab00cmf
/u01/app/oracle/dirprm/fm00lsk
```

I need to find the last `/` of every line, and then print the next two characters.

For example, my output should be:

```
ab
fm
```

Comment: This is a work order, not a question. Isn't any demonstrated effort required?

Answer (score 7):

With `grep` that supports [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions):

```
grep -oP '.*/\K.{0,2}' infile
```

- This `\K` assertion is used to ignore everything matched before itself
- `.{0,2}` matches zero or maximum two characters after last `/`

For the input below:

```
/u01/app/oracle/dirprm/fm00lsk
/foo/x/ab00cmf
/foo/bar/x
/foo/somthing/
```

The output would be:

```
fm
ab
x
```

Comment: Shouldn't '/' be escaped? e.g., `grep -oP '.*\/\K.{0,2}' infile`

Comment: An unescaped forward slash may cause issues if copying/pasting this expression into code. Saw this at [RegExr](https://regexr.com).

Comment: no, `/` has no special meaning in grep.

Comment: @PauloTomé [there](https://regexr.com/) because it uses for replacement, and since default delimiter is `/` so it needs to be escaped, or change the delimiter to something else different from `/` then no need to be escaped, see https://regex101.com/r/jR55PC/2 I have changed delimiter to `@`. however as I said `/` has no special meaning in grep to worry about escaping it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F/ '{print substr($NF,1,2)}' C1.log
```

This uses `/` as a field separator and then prints two characters from the last field starting at character 1.

Comment: Thank you. It's working.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the currently greyed-out checkmark below the vote counter) so that others facing a similar problem may find it more easily.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` greedy matching and back references:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^.*\/)(..)(.*$)/\2/' C1.log
ab
fm
$
```

Comment: But you don’t need to capture the substrings that you aren’t using: ```sed -E 's/^.*\/(..).*$/\1/'```.

Comment: @Scott. Indeed that is true.